Customer Address Design Probelm
I'm designing a database for E-commercial. So the Customer have many address also 1 address also has many customers owned so I have another CustomerAddress table (many-to-many relation). Here detail :

Customer:

CustomerID (PK)
Name
DateofBirth


AddressNote :

AddressNoteID (PK)
AddressID (FK) (has a relationship with the city table so I'm not mentioning it here)


CustomerAddress :

CustomerID (PK)

AddressNoteID (PK)

PhoneNumber (The phone number here indicates who will be called upon delivery at that address)




My problem is that I want 1 client will have multiple addresses but will have 1 single default address. So I thinking to add one more column  IsDefault (bool) in CustomerAddress table. Later, I feel wrong because that's still allowed customer have two different addresses and both set Default address. I believe in application level validation can handle this but I want database constraints. Is there anyway to design this constraints. I'm just beginner so thank for any instructions.

One alternative would be to have a supplementary "CustomerDefaultAddress" table, which just has CustomerID and AddressNoteID columns (are they your "key" fields for the CustomerAddress table) - then you can set Primary Key (or just uniqueness constraint) on the CustomerID column (to ensure that you can only have a single record per customer, that either gets inserted - if no default address is set for a customer yet - or updated, when the customer's default address changes

One way to implement such a constraint is by using a filtered unique index:
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX foobar ON customeraddress (customerid)
WHERE isdefault = 'Y'

Fiddle
